# Type-level Map with DataKinds

Tags: haskell, type-inference, data-kinds

I have a common pattern where I have a type-level list of kind `[*]`, and I would like to apply a type constructor of kind `* -> *` to each element in the list. For example, I would like to change the type `'[Int, Double, Integer]` to `'[Maybe Int, Maybe Double, Maybe Integer]`.

Here's my attempt to implement a type-level `map`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, TypeOperators, DataKinds, ScopedTypeVariables, GADTs #-}

-- turns a type list '[b1, b2, b3]
-- into the type list '[a b1, a b2, a b3]
class TypeMap (a :: * -> *) (bs :: [*]) where
    type Map a bs :: [*]

instance TypeMap a '[b] where
    type Map a '[b] = '[a b]

instance TypeMap a (b1 ': b2 ': bs) where
    type Map a (b1 ': b2 ': bs) = ((a b1) ': (Map a (b2 ': bs)))


data HList :: [*] -> * where
              HNil :: HList '[]
              HCons :: a -> HList as -> HList (a ': as)

class Foo as where
    toLists :: HList as -> HList (Map [] as)

instance Foo '[a] where
    toLists (HCons a HNil) = HCons [a] HNil

instance (Foo (a2 ': as)) =>  Foo (a1 ': a2 ': as) where
    toLists (HCons a as) = 
        let as' = case (toLists as) of
                    (HCons a2 as'') -> HCons [head a2] as'' -- ERROR
        in HCons [a] as'
```

This results in the error

```
Could not deduce (a3 ~ [t0])
    from the context (Foo ((':) * a2 as))
      bound by the instance declaration at Test.hs:35:10-50
    or from ((':) * a1 ((':) * a2 as) ~ (':) * a as1)
      bound by a pattern with constructor
                 HCons :: forall a (as :: [*]).
                          a -> HList as -> HList ((':) * a as),
               in an equation for `toLists'
      at Test.hs:36:14-23
    or from (Map [] as1 ~ (':) * a3 as2)
      bound by a pattern with constructor
                 HCons :: forall a (as :: [*]).
                          a -> HList as -> HList ((':) * a as),
               in a case alternative
      at Test.hs:38:22-34
      `a3' is a rigid type variable bound by
           a pattern with constructor
             HCons :: forall a (as :: [*]).
                      a -> HList as -> HList ((':) * a as),
           in a case alternative
           at Test.hs:38:22
    Expected type: HList (Map [] ((':) * a2 as))
      Actual type: HList ((':) * [t0] as2)
    In the return type of a call of `HCons'
    In the expression: HCons [head a2] as''
    In a case alternative: (HCons a2 as'') -> HCons [head a2] as''
```

I've tried adding copious type annotations, but the error more or less comes out the same: GHC can't even infer that the first element of the HList is a (normal) list. Am I doing something silly here? Something illegal? Or is there any way around?

Comment: Why don't you have a `TypeMap a []` instance?

Comment: @DanielWagner Agreed, those instances should probably be for '[] and (a ': as).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you wrote `TypeMap a (b1 ': b2 ': bs)`, that isn't consistent with the recursion you did to define Map... which only leads to an error when you try to TypeMap lists that aren't 1 or 2 elements long. Also, it's cleaner in your case to just have a type family for this.

```
type family TypeMap (a :: * -> *) (xs :: [*]) :: [*]
type instance TypeMap t '[] = '[]
type instance TypeMap t (x ': xs) = t x ': TypeMap t xs
```

Note this is pretty much a direct translation of:

```
map f [] = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the type family solution; that's much cleaner than the classes.

Answer (score 4):

The minimal change that makes your code compile is to change your instances for `[a]` and `b1:b2:bs` into instances for `[]` and `b:bs`.

```
instance TypeMap a '[] where
    type Map a '[] = '[]

instance TypeMap a (b ': bs) where
    type Map a (b ': bs) = a b ': Map a bs
```

Comment: @Eric I suspect the problem goes like this: your recursive call matches against `HCons`, which means you expect that the recursive type-level call will also make a cons cell readily apparent. But since there are two possible instances to choose from, that is not readily apparent -- it involves some reasoning about closedness of type classes that GHC doesn't (and probably shouldn't try to) do. With the fix, if there's a cons cell readily apparent as an argument to `TypeMap`, there's only one instance that GHC can choose, so it chooses it.