# Anonymous Type Functions

Tags: haskell, anonymous-function, data-kinds, type-constructor

This is a followup to a previous question: [Type-level Map with DataKinds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191348/type-level-map-with-datakinds), starting with from the two answers it received.

My goal is to take a `HList` of arbitrary types and turn it into a list of related/derived types

```
type family TypeMap (a :: * -> *) (xs :: [*]) :: [*]
type instance TypeMap t '[] = '[]
type instance TypeMap t (x ': xs) = t x ': TypeMap t xs

data HList :: [*] -> * where
          HNil :: HList '[]
          HCons :: a -> HList as -> HList (a ': as)
```

When I actually tried to do this with a few types, I ran into a problem. The type-function " argument to TypeMap has to take the `HList` element type as its last argument and return a new type. This works okay sometimes:

```
test :: HList rqs -> HList (TypeMap ((,) Int) rqs)
test HNil = HNil
test (HCons x xs) = HCons (3,x) $ test xs
```

But what if I wanted to switch the order of the tuple in the definition of test? 
My first attempt was to define a type synonym:

```
type RevIntTup b = (b,Int)

test2 :: HList rqs -> HList (TypeMap RevIntTup rqs)
test2 HNil = HNil
test2 (HCons x xs) = HCons (x,3) $ test2 xs
```

But of course, [you can't partially apply type synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922560/why-doesnt-typesynonyminstances-allow-partially-applied-type-synonyms-to-be-use), which would certainly do the trick. Is there any (other) way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to write a `FlipTypeMap`... but that's not very composable. A better choice here might be to do the type-level version of  `map ($ 2) (map (/) [1,2,3])` instead of `map (flip (/) 2) [1,2,3]` by taking advantage of `-XPolyKinds`:

```
type family TypeMap (a :: j -> k) (xs :: [j]) :: [k]
type instance TypeMap t '[] = '[]
type instance TypeMap t (x ': xs) = t x ': TypeMap t xs

type family ApList (xs :: [j -> k]) (a :: j) :: [k]
type instance ApList '[] t = '[]
type instance ApList (x ': xs) t = x t ': ApList xs t

test2 :: HList rqs -> HList (TypeMap (,) rqs `ApList` Int)
test2 HNil = HNil
test2 (HCons x xs) = HCons (x,3) $ test2 xs
```

Answer (score 1):

aavogt's answer certainly got the job done, but I discovered an alternate solution using `Data.Promotion` from the [singletons library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons). This library already includes type families for `Flip`, `Map`, `$`, and much of the rest of the Prelude.

For example,

```
test2 :: HList rqs -> HList (Map (FlipSym1 (TyCon2 (,)) $ Int) rqs)
test2 HNil = HNil
test2 (HCons x xs) = HCons (x,3) $ test2 xs
```

which is comes almost directly from [this amazing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048620/data-promotion-syntax).