# Data Promotion Syntax

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-promotion

I recently discovered the `Data.Promotion` half of [singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-1.0). It has loads of type families which allow essentially arbitrary computation at the type level. I have a couple of questions about usage:

1. What is the difference between [`($)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-1.0/docs/src/Data-Singletons-Prelude-Base.html#%24), [`(%$)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-1.0/docs/src/Data-Singletons-Prelude-Base.html#%24), [`($$)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-1.0/docs/src/Data-Singletons-Prelude-Base.html#%24), and are they related to `:++$`, `:.$`, etc? Are these actually infix operators? I was [under the impression](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/InfixTypeConstructors) all infix type constructors had to begin with a `:`.
2. I'm trying to map a constructor over a list:

   ```
   {-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeOperators, PolyKinds #-}
   import Data.Promotion.Prelude

   data Foo a b
   type MyList = '[Int, Double, Float]

    -- expects one more argument to `Foo`
   type FooList1 b = Map ((Flip Foo) $ b) MyList

   -- parse error on the second `b`
   type FooList2 b = Map (($ b) :. Foo) MyList
   ```

   but I'm having trouble using a multi-parameter type constructor. Ideas?
3. I was able to replace all of the type functions I had written with equivalent functions from `Data.Promotion` except this one:

   ```
   type family ListToConstraint (xs :: [Constraint]) :: Constraint
   type instance ListToConstraint '[] = ()
   type instance ListToConstraint (x ': xs) = (x, ListToConstraint xs)
   ```

   Is there some kind of magic going on with the `Constraint` kind that would prevent its manipulation as nested pairs?

Comment: All infix _data constructors_ need to begin with a colon, but there is no such thing as an "infix type-constructor variable" (which would be the equivalent to a value-level infix) so there's no need to require that distinction in the type language.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, of course, there used to be.  Some old code with arrows would use the `Arrow (~>)` constraint, which I found to be nicely evocative. I enjoy being able to say `type (*) = (,)` and `type (+) = Either` also, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. As has been explained in the comments, there's no longer a syntactic requirement for infix functions on the type level to start with a colon. So yes, all these are infix operators. No two infix operators are automatically related to each other, but the singletons library uses some naming conventions internally, to relate symbols used for *defunctionalization* (see below) to their normal counterparts.
2. There's a whole bunch of problems arising from the fact that type families cannot be partially applied, but datatypes can. That's why the singletons library uses a technique called *defunctionalization*: for each partially applied type function, it defines a datatype. There's then a (very large and open) type family called `Apply` that takes all these datatypes that represent partially applied functions and suitable arguments and performs the actual application.

   The kind of such defunctionalized representations of type functions is

   ```
   TyFun k1 k2 -> *
   ```

   for various reasons (btw, a good introduction to all this is in Richard Eisenberg's blog post ["Defunctionalization for the win"](http://typesandkinds.wordpress.com/2013/04/01/defunctionalization-for-the-win/)), whereas the kind of the corresponding "normal" type function would be

   ```
   k1 -> k2
   ```

   Now all higher-order type functions in singletons expect defunctionalized arguments. For example, the kind of `Map` is

   ```
   Map :: (TyFun k k1 -> *) -> [k] -> [k1]
   ```

   and not

   ```
   Map :: (k -> k1) -> [k] -> [k1]
   ```

   Now let's look at the functions you're working with:

   ```
   Flip :: (TyFun k (TyFun k1 k2 -> *) -> *) -> k1 -> k -> k2
   ```

   The first argument is a defunctionalized curried function of kind `k -> k1 -> k2`, and it turns this into a normal type function of kind `k1 -> k -> k2`.

   Also:

   ```
   ($) :: (TyFun k1 k -> *) -> k1 -> k
   ```

   This is just a synonym for the `Apply` I mentioned above.

   Now let's look at your example:

   ```
   type FooList1 b = Map ((Flip Foo) $ b) MyList  -- fails
   ```

   There are two problems here: First, `Foo` is a datatype and not a defunctionalized symbol as `Flip` expects. Second, `Flip` is a type family and expects three arguments, but only one is provided. We can fix the first problem by applying `TyCon2`, which takes a normal datatype and turns it into a defunctionalized symbol:

   ```
   TyCon2 :: (k -> k1 -> k2) -> TyFun k (TyFun k1 k2 -> *) -> *
   ```

   For the second problem, we need one of the partial applications of `Flip` that singletons already defines for us:

   ```
   FlipSym0 :: TyFun (TyFun k1 (TyFun k2 k -> *) -> *)
                     (TyFun k2 (TyFun k1 k -> *) -> *)
               -> *
   FlipSym1 ::    (TyFun k1 (TyFun k2 k -> *) -> *)
               -> TyFun k2 (TyFun k1 k -> *) -> *

   FlipSym2 ::    (TyFun k1 (TyFun k2 k -> *) -> *)
               -> k2 -> TyFun k1 k -> *

   Flip     ::    (TyFun k (TyFun k1 k2 -> *) -> *)
               -> k1 -> k -> k2
   ```

   If you look closely, then `FlipSymN` is the representation required if `Flip` is partially applied to `N` arguments, and `Flip` corresponds to the imaginary `FlipSym3`. In the example, `Flip` is applied to one argument, so the corrected example becomes

   ```
   type FooList1 b = Map ((FlipSym1 (TyCon2 Foo)) $ b) MyList
   ```

   And this works:

   ```
   GHCi> :kind! FooList1 Char
   FooList1 Char :: [*]
   = '[Foo Int Char, Foo Double Char, Foo Float Char]
   ```

   The second example is similar:

   ```
   type FooList2 b = Map (($ b) :. Foo) MyList
   ```

   Here, we have the following problems: again, `Foo` must be turned into a defunctionalized symbol using `TyCon2`; operator sections such as `$ b` are not available on the type level, hence the parse error. We'll have to use `Flip` again, but this time `FlipSym2`, because we apply it to the operator `$` and `b`. Oh, but then `$` is partially applied, so we need a symbol corresponding to `$` with 0 arguments. This is available as `$$` in singletons (for symbolic operators, the defunctionalized symbols have appended `$`s). And finally, `:.` is also partially applied: it expects three operators, but has been given only two. So we go from `:.` to `:.$$$` (three dollars because one dollar corresponds to `0`, and three dollars correspond to `2`). All in all:

   ```
   type FooList2 b = Map ((FlipSym2 ($$) b) :.$$$ TyCon2 Foo) MyList
   ```

   And again, this works:

   ```
   GHCi> :kind! FooList2 Char
   FooList2 Char :: [*]
   = '[Foo Int Char, Foo Double Char, Foo Float Char]
   ```
3. I may be blind, but I don't think this is contained in singletons, which is not all that much concerned with `Constraint`s. It's a useful function, though. It's in a [library I'm currently working on](https://github.com/kosmikus/tilt/blob/master/src/Data/Type/Constraint.hs). It's still unfinished and mostly undocumented, though, that's why I haven't released it yet.

Comment: An exceptional answer! It's too bad the solution is uglier than a regular old data-level programmer such as myself might expect. The lack of partially applied type synonyms just keeps coming back to haunt me.

Comment: As an aside, I noticed that I quoted you in a recent (unanswered) [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684947/when-is-xallowambiguoustypes-appropriate). Since you seem to be resident `AllowAmbiguousTypes` expert, perhaps you'd weigh in and enlighten us all!

Comment: I've since misused singletons, so here's what *not* to do with the above info: don't use `TyCon*` on type families! There's a [bug](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9888) in GHC that makes it appear as though this works, but it [really doesn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490352/type-family-shenanigans-in-ghci).