# Type Family Shenanigans in GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghc

Here's my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, TypeOperators, DataKinds, PolyKinds, FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances #-}

module Foo where

import Data.Singletons.Prelude
import Data.Type.Equality

data TP a b

-- foldl (\(bool, r) x -> (bool && (r == x), r)) (True, head xs) xs
type family Same (b :: Bool) (r :: k) (rq :: [k]) :: k where
  Same bool r (x ': xs) = Same (bool :&& (r == x)) r xs
  Same bool r '[] = TP bool r

data NotEqualFailure
-- converts a True result to a type
type family EqResult tp where
  EqResult (TP 'True r) = r
  EqResult (TP 'False r) = NotEqualFailure



data Zq q i
type family Foo rq
type instance Foo (Zq q i) = i
type R = 
  EqResult 
    (Same 'True (Foo (Zq Double Int)) 
      (Map (TyCon1 Foo) 
        '[Zq Double Int, Zq Float Int]))

f :: R
f = 3
```

This doesn't compile in GHC 7.8.3:

```
No instance for (Num NotEqualFailure)
      arising from a use of ‘f’
    In the expression: f
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = f
```

but if I comment out `f` and start GHCi:

```
> :kind! R
R :: *
= Int
```

So GHC can't seem to decide if the elements in my list are equal or not. If they are equal, `EqResult` should return the common type (`Int` here), otherwise it returns `NotEqualFailure`. Can anyone explain what's going on here? Let me know if you also think this looks like a bug, and I'll file it on the GHC trac.

If you can figure out a way to write "EqResult (Same ...)" in a different way, it might get around this issue.

---

**EDIT**
I rewrote the type family, but unfortunately I'm having essentially the same problem. The code is smaller and simpler now.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, TypeOperators, DataKinds, FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances #-}

module Foo where

import Data.Singletons.Prelude
import Data.Singletons.Prelude.List
import Data.Type.Equality

-- foldl (\(bool, r) x -> (bool && (r == x), r)) (True, head xs) xs
type family Same rq where
  Same (x ': xs) = 
    EqResult (And (Map ((TyCon2 (==)) $ x) xs)) x

data NotEqualFailure
-- converts a True result to a type
type family EqResult b v where
  EqResult 'True r = r
  EqResult 'False r = NotEqualFailure

type R = Same '[Int, Int]

f :: R
f = 3
```

GHCi can still resolve `R` to `Int`, but GHC can't resolve the type family for `EqResult` at all now (before it incorrectly resolved it to `NotEqualFailure`). Note that this example works if I change the size of the list to one, i.e. `'[Int]`.

---

**EDIT 2**
I removed all external libraries, and got everything to work. This solution is probably the smallest, but I still want to know why the larger examples appear to break GHC.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DataKinds,
             UndecidableInstances #-}

module Foo where

type family Same (rq :: [*]) :: * where
  Same (x ': xs) = EqTo x xs

--tests if x==y for all x\in xs
type family EqTo y xs where
  EqTo y '[] = y
  EqTo y (y ': xs) = EqTo y xs
  EqTo y (x ': xs) = NotEqualFailure

data NotEqualFailure

type R = Same '[Int, Int]
f :: R
f = 3
```

Comment: I also tried out a variety of solutions, and it seems that things break when we bring `Map` in the picture. I also tried it with a simpler Map (not defunctionalized like the `singletons` version), but it didn't work either.

Comment: Woo hoo, now it's a [ghc ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9888).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is in fact a bug, and it [will be fixed](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9433) in the next release of GHC.